# How to enforce AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder to take key and secret from the code

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

We have the key and secret stored as system enviornment variables and AWS connection reads it from there. We want to move the key and secrets to a vault and access them through APIs.

Is there a way to enforce *AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder* to take the keys from within the code?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but you should be able to create a DynamoDbClient that has a custom credentials provider. For example, where `myProvider` implements the `AwsCredentialsProvider` interface:

```
DynamoDbClient client = DynamoDbClient.builder()
                        .region(Region.US_EAST_1)
                        .credentialsProvider(myProvider)
                        .build();
```